# rails has_many association pass params to new form for create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a has_many association I would like to pass to the the list_advice_id to the New form for AdvisorConnection.  My models are below:

```
class ListAdvice < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :advisor_connections, :dependent => :destroy 
end

class AdvisorConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list_advice
    belongs_to :users
end
```

On the list_advice show form, I have a link_to as shown below:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Book Advisor', new_advisor_connection_path %></td>
```

On the advisor_connections controller new action, I have:

```
@advisor_connection = AdvisorConnection.new
@advisor_connection = @list_advice.advisor_connection.find(params[:list_advice])
```

After looking at many examples, I don't know how to pull the list_advice_id into the advisor_connection new form so it will use the has_many association to show on New and then save on Create.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to rails, too, so this might not be the correct answer.  But it looks like you are trying to use multiple models on the same form.  This railscast was very helpful to me

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to pass my has_many association from one model form to another new model form and use the associated id from the previous form.

Comment: An update, I am trying to just do the create directly from the link_to, I have below, but am gettin undefined method advisor_connections:        <td><%= link_to 'Book Advisor', {:controller=>advisor_connections, :action => :create}, :method => :post %></td>

Comment: Ok, have the link_to working now with:      <td><%= link_to 'Book Advisor', :controller=>:advisor_connections, :action=>:create, :method =>:post %></td>
Now need to figure out how it will create the new object using the has_many association.  Do I need to add a param to pass it through or does has_many handle that?